# About the formula of the Taylor microscale

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, scales

I am running simulations of a non-isotropic turbulent flow and I need to compute the Taylor microscale. The formula one can find in the book Turbulent flows (Stephen B. Pope) is :

$\lambda = \sqrt{10} \ \eta^{\frac{2}{3}} \ L^{\frac{1}{3}} \quad$     (Eq (6.62) in the book), with :

-$\lambda$ being the Taylor microscale

-$\eta$ being the Kolmogorov scale

-$L = k^{\frac{3}{2}} \ \epsilon^{-1}  $ being the macroscale

This yields $\lambda = \sqrt{ 10 \frac{\nu \ k}{\epsilon} }$

**My question is : where does the $\sqrt{10}$ come from?** I'm still looking into it in the literature but so far I don't find any explanation for this factor.

Thank you very much for any help you may provide.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/742395/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34832/226902

Answer (score 1):

The Karman-Howarth equation is,

$$\partial_t(\langle u^2\rangle f(r,t))=-2\langle u^2\rangle^{3/2} \left( \partial_r h +\frac{4}{r}h\right)+2\nu \langle u^2\rangle \left( \partial^2_r f+\frac{4}{r}\partial_r f\right)$$

Where the second and third order correlation tensors can be expressed solely in terms of $f$ and $h$, respectively (lets not forget that we are assuming homogeneous and isotropic turbulence). Now, from symmetry arguments if we expand $f$ and $h$ in Taylor series, the leading order of $h$ is 3 and the order 1 term of $f$ vanishes:

$$f=1+\frac{1}{2}f_2r^2+...$$
$$h=\frac{1}{6}f_2r^3+...$$

If we replace these approximations in the K-H equation, evaluating at $r=0$ and considering that $f(0,t)=1$ we obtain the following relation,

$$\partial_t \langle u ^2\rangle=10\nu \langle u ^2\rangle f_2$$

Now, $f_2$ is the coefficient of a Taylor expansion, then it's the second derivative evaluated at $r=0$, $f_2=\partial^2_2 f \rvert_{r=0}$. Now, the Taylor microscale is related with $f$ by the following expression (Batchelor, 1959):

$$f(r)\approx 1-\frac{r^2}{2\lambda^2}$$

Then $f_2=-1/\lambda^2$. From the result obtained before,

$$\lambda^2=-\frac{1}{f_2}=-10\nu \langle u ^2\rangle (\partial_t \langle u ^2\rangle)^{-1}$$

This result is eq. (6.77) in Pope's book. Now in the same equation they relate de derivative of the kinetic energy with the dissipation, $\frac{d\langle u ^2\rangle}{dt}=-(2/3)\epsilon$, with $\langle u ^2\rangle=\frac{2}{3}k$, replacing in the expression we get $\lambda^2=10\frac{\nu k}{\epsilon}$ or,

$$\lambda=\sqrt{10}\sqrt{\frac{\nu k}{\epsilon}}$$

If you need more information about the derivations you can check the paper by von Karman and Howarth, 'On the Statistical Theory of Isotropic Turbulence'(1938) and book by Batchelor, 'Theory of Homogeneous Turbulence' (1959).