# Calculating an anisotropic or component Taylor microscale

Tags: turbulence, scales

The Taylor microscale in isotropic turbulence is given by:

$$\lambda = \sqrt{ 15 \frac{\nu \ v'^2}{\epsilon} }$$

where v' is the root mean square of the velocity fluctuations.  In general, for velocity fluctuations in three dimensions:

$$v' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{{v'_1}^2+{v'_2}^2+{v'_3}^2}$$

So plugging this expression into the Taylor microscale equation yields:

$$\lambda = \sqrt{ 5 \frac{\nu}{\epsilon} }\sqrt{{v'_1}^2+{v'_2}^2+{v'_3}^2}$$

Now for isotropic turbulence
$$ v'_1=v'_2=v'_3$$

So for isotropic turbulence, equation 3 (third equation in this text) yields:

$$\lambda = \sqrt{ 5 \frac{\nu}{\epsilon} }\sqrt{{3v'_1}^2} = \sqrt{ 15 \frac{\nu \ {v'_1}^2}{\epsilon} }$$

My question is: can I use equation 3 to calculate the Taylor microscale for anisotropic turbulence.  For example if the injection of energy is highly anisotropic where $v'_2 = v'_3=0$

$$\lambda_A = \sqrt{ 5 \frac{\nu}{\epsilon} }\sqrt{{v'_1}^2}=\sqrt{ 5 \frac{\nu \ {v'_1}^2}{\epsilon} }$$

where $\lambda_A$ is the anisotropic Taylor microscale. Does this seem correct? Also, does anyone know of a reference where this derivation was already done?

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is a simplification of some general form of Taylor microscales that can be defined as
$$
\lambda_{\alpha, \beta}^2 = \frac{\left<u_{\alpha}^2\right>}{\left<\left( \frac{\partial u_{\alpha}}{\partial x_{\beta}}\right)^2\right>}
$$
Brackets here represent a spatial average. I took the definition from [this paper](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1226210). You can have a look at section 6.3 in Pope's book for the derivation in homogeneous isotropic turbulence that leads to your first formula.

So strictly speaking, I would not recommand your third equation. But that would be a good exercise to identify the amount of error one can make by using this approximated expression.